# no method error in one to many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :clubs, :dependent => :destroy
 has_many :announcements, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

models/announcement.rb

```
class Announcement < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :club
end
```

models/club.rb

```
class Club < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :announcements, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

controllers/announcements/announcements_controller.rb

```
def index
 @announcements = Announcement.find(:all, :include => [:user, :club])
end
```

**Problem:**

When i type this code,

views/announcements/index.html.erb

```
<% @announcements.each do |announcement| %>
 <%= announcement.user.username %>
<% end %>
```

I get this error:

```
NoMethodError in Announcements#index
 undefined method `username' for nil:NilClass
```

when i change code to this, it works.

```
<% @announcements.each do |announcement| %>
 <%= announcement.club.user.username %>
<% end %>
```

Why is the first code is not working? What is the difference between these codes. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like one of your announcements doesn't have a user associated.  Use `rails console` and review your Announcements objects to see if this is the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you've got an announcement which has no user set, but does have a club which in turn does have a user. Perhaps consider adding a validation to require that the `:user_id` column on announcement is present.